# True for every formula.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

For a formula $ \gamma = r \iff (p_1 \vee p_2) $ there is true that: $\rho \models \gamma \iff \rho(r) = \max(\rho(p_1), \rho(p_2))$

Is it a true for every formula `r`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very terse and hard to understand. It is particularly confusing to use a symbol like $\iff$ both as an object language symbol (i.e., to form formulas) and as a metalanguage symbol (i.e., to abbreviate assertions about formulas). Let me write out (rather verbosely, by way of contrast) what I think you mean:

> *If $\gamma$ is the formula $r \Leftrightarrow (p_1 \lor p_2)$, is it true that under any assignment $\rho$, $\rho$ satisfies $\gamma$ iff the truth value $\rho(r)$ of $r$ under $\rho$ is equal to the larger of the truth values $\rho(p_1)$ and $\rho(p_2)$ (where we adopt the usual ordering of truth values so that truth is greater than falsehood)?*

Assuming the usual definitions of everything involved, this is true and can be proved quite directly from the definition of the satisfaction relation $\models$. If you are having problems with this, you need to give some more details about the particular definitions you are working with and what you have tried.